# how to echo $, & symbols correctly?

Tags: shell

Output `&a` on the screen while there is already a defined variable `a`. Here is what happened in my bash:

```
localhost:~ $ a=5
localhost:~ $ echo $$a
83079a
localhost:~ $ echo ^$a
^5
localhost:~ $
```

I just can't get `$a`.

And I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087695/escaping-ampersands-in-windows-batch-files

it says  `echo a ^& b` will get `a & b`, but with my bash I got this:

```
localhost:~ $ echo a ^& b
[1] 83134
a ^
-bash: b: command not found
```

Comment: did you try to excape using back slash instead of '^' ?

Comment: works. thanks! sorry I never thought of that ...

Comment: You can also place things in single quotes `'` to get the literal form of anything

Comment: You shouldn't be looking at windows batch file information for help with bash. They are different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double quotes to `echo` a variable

```
localhost:~ $ a=5
localhost:~ $ echo "$a"
5
localhost:~ $ echo '$a'
$a
localhost:~ $ echo "a & b"
a & b
```

Or backslash `\` to escape and not use quotes

```
localhost:~ $ echo a \& b
a & b
localhost:~ $ echo \$a
$a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r@S:/tmp # a=10
r@S:/tmp # echo $a
10
r@S:/tmp # echo \$a
$a
r@S:/tmp #
```